# Is there a Natbib style that creates a bibliography like 'abbrvnat', but sorted like 'unsrtnat'?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

In my latex file I am using natbib for the citations with `abbrvnat` style.

Is there a way to show citation numbers in order like in `unsrtnat` while keeping the abbreviated form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I"m not aware of any, but you can easily create custom styles using `makebst` ([makebst.pdf](ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/makebst.pdf))

The *makebst.tex* and at least *merlin.mbs* file from [ctan: custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) are required.
Simply call

```
latex makebst
```

and follow the instructions to create your own customized stylefile.